Struts2-core.jar problem running with Java 11: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3
I´ve been running Java 11 and Struts 2 for a while (about more than 6 month) and everything were fine by far, everything was working and running...
But early last week, I got a problem saying:

java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\C:\Users\xxxuserxx\eclipse-workspace-migration.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ProEnergiaWeb\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.3.37.jar

This problem is in my development environment:  Windows + Eclipse. I read some threads in stackoverflow. There  people says struts2-core-2.3.37.jar has an issue running in windows. But, as I said before, everything was just fine untill now.
Did anyone have this problem? Any tips or ideas.
I tried creating a new workspace + new instance of tomcat server.
I tried setting eclipse build path, Java compiler, etc...
I tried updating Maven dependencies in my project.
And I don't know what is broken right now.
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\C:\Users\ricardodias\eclipse-workspace-migration-2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ProEnergiaWeb\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.3.37.jar
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
at java.base/java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2290)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1222)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:726)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:843)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:246)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:176)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:317)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.JarEntryRevision.needsReloading(JarEntryRevision.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManager.fileNeedsReloading(DefaultFileManager.java:66)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.needsReload(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:169)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.needReloadContainerProviders(ConfigurationManager.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.conditionalReload(ConfigurationManager.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:73)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:978)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.createActionContext(PrepareOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1786)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


Post a complete stacktrace.

@RomanC Hi, RomanC, I just posted. Check it out.

It is a bug WW-4970:

This issue was fixed in Struts 2.5.14 but the fix never made it to the Struts 2.3 branch.


But it was working for a long time and it never crashed until now. I wondering how it was working.

There should be an example how to reproduce a bug. You can also post debugging details, so I can look at it. Or tell me what has been changed since you fall into this issue.

Actually, the application does not start. When I start up tomcat and try to load the login page in the web browser the error message showed in the post is thrown. No chances for debugging. And more, I was working using my IDE with a local tomcat server up... everything was fine. Then, few minutes later, I could not have my application running again.

And what did you do with application during this few minutes?

I just tried to debug code. My teammates also downloaded the project from Git. Last week it was not working, same error message. Yesterday he downloaded again and it worked. I am trying to figure out what is going on. This is very tricky.

Because it is a bug, that was going on. It happened while you were debugging. And it might not caught if you run it in production environment.
